# How can I iterate more quickly when creating a snap?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I am working on a snap of a bigger piece of software and building the snap, removing the old one, installing the new one just takes a very long time.

I would like to iterate over creating the snap and testing things out more quickly. I know that the snap builds just fine, now I'm interested in testing things like launching the app and its integration. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Preface

One way to go about this is to use `snap try`. From its `--help` message:

```
The try command installs an unpacked snap into the system for testing
purposes. The unpacked snap content continues to be used even after 
installation, so non-metadata changes there go live instantly. Metadata
changes such as those performed in snap.yaml will require reinstallation 
to go live.
```

It also comes with an option:

```
--devmode     Install in development mode and disable confinement
```

This is particularly helpful if you want to test confinement bits and getting the use of interfaces right.

## Usage

The way to use this is simple, just run:

```
snapcraft prime
snap try prime/
```

In the first step you tell `snapcraft` to do the

```
Final copy and preparation for the snap.
```

And in the second step `snapd` makes use of the contents of the directory to "install" the snap. Now you can play around with the package while still being able to make changes to it.

## Example

Let's use an example from [the Snappy Playpen](https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen) to show how to use this.

We are using consul as it's relatively quick to build and use:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen
$ cd snappy-playpen/consul/
snappy-playpen/consul$ snapcraft prime
Preparing to pull consul 
[...]
Staging consul 
Priming consul 
snappy-playpen/consul$
```

Now let's make sure that we don't have another version installed of it and then proceed with the installation.

```
snappy-playpen/consul$ which consul
snappy-playpen/consul$ snap try prime

Name    Version  Rev  Developer  Notes
consul  0.6.4    x1              try
snappy-playpen/consul$ consul --help
usage: consul [--version] [--help] <command> [<args>]

Available commands are:
    agent          Runs a Consul agent
[...]
snappy-playpen/consul$
```

So far so good. It seems to work just fine. Now let's replace it with `/bin/echo` just to see how things work:

```
snappy-playpen/consul$ cp /bin/echo prime/bin/consul 
snappy-playpen/consul$ consul --help
Usage: /snap/consul/x1/bin/consul [SHORT-OPTION]... [STRING]...
   or:  /snap/consul/x1/bin/consul LONG-OPTION
Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.
[...]
daniel@daydream:/tmp/test/snappy-playpen/consul$
```

As you can see, we can make changes to the live system in `prime` while still running things under confinement. This is generally a good way to get the snap up and running and fully tested quickly.

**Note:** With `snapd` before 2.0.10 (2016-07-09), you had to temove the snap before running `snapcraft clean` or `snapd` would get into a bad state and whine about being unable to find mounted snaps. Some more fixes are lined up for 2.0.11, which should land in a few days as well.

Comment: You might consider mentioning that the snap should be removed before one runs `snapcraft clean` or snapd currently gets into a bad state and whines about being unable to find mounted snaps. The fix is in progress for that, but not yet released.

Comment: Nice one! Adding the info now.

Comment: Yeah, 'snap try' is for exactly this use case. It allows you to make a directory and build your snap in it, without having to keep making the squashfs and remount it. You iterate just by working in that directory (you effectively have a read-write snap) until you are happy, then make the squashfs out of that directory.