# How do I use snappy-debug to debug a snap?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap, debugging

I am attempting to use the snap "snappy-debug" to watch the behavior of a snap (specifically trying to use strace on containers run with the lxd snap in order to watch their behavior)  Unfortunately, there is no documentation on snappy-debug.

I have found references on using snappy-debug, such as this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783979/how-do-i-debug-snaps/784113#784113), but they only show me how to use that one capability of snappy-debug.  Snappy-debug is quoted as having strace in the snap description, but I can't find documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The description for snappy-debug is incorrect. The tools mentioned in the description were removed in revision 3 of the source code of the package, as seen below:-

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~snappy-dev/snappy-hub/snappy-debug/revision/3

The following description was given:-

> Per snappy core team, remove gdb, ltrace and strace binaries and corresponding binaries in package.yaml. Also remove valgrind from package.yaml. In this manner, snappy-security can be shipped for all architectures. These removed tools will be added in a future update.

So, you're using the single feature 'scanlog' of snappy-debug, the other tools may come back later.